# Arranging page in a single big table

Tags: tables

I'm a LaTeX beginner, so I apologise in advance if the question has an obvious solution or has already been answered.
I have to write a short technical report on a lab experiment for college, and the teacher gave us a template in .doc format saying that we can use any typesetting program we wanted as long as the final product bears some resemblance to the template. Now, I'd like to use LaTeX for the ease of drawing graphs and tables etc., but I don't know how to typeset something like this.

[Edit] This is what i've come up with; i don't know how to further subdivide the bottom right column, and several part of my code are clumsy (namely, i want the table to always fit the whole available regardless of what thext it's inside)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
\hline
 & \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Report Tecnico} & Data: XX/YY/ZZ \\
                & Nome File : xxxx.yyy\\ 
                 & \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ }\\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Titolo: }\\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ }\\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{".................."}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Progetto o ordine di riferimento:}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ }\\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{"......................"}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{REF. {\#}data}\\
\hline

Autore: AAA BBBB & \\
& \multirow{2}{*}{Descrizione Revisioni}\\ 
 & \\
Approvato da: CCC DDDD & \\

\hline
 & \\
Destinatari: & 0\qquad Primo rilascio Rev 0 \qquad data\\
 & \\

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Anyone to the rescue?

[image]

Comment: Is this a one-page-only document or you need to extend the table to other pages?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you made an attempt and composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem showing how far you can get.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem and helping you understand the specific difficulties you are having.

Comment: @dcmst no, it's a multi-page document but that's the only one i need formatted like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `tabularx` and some `p` columns to ensure that the contents does not go out of margin. Also since the widths are expressed as `\textwidth` fractions, it should be easy to adapt the table in case you change the margins (I'm supposing that you don't want the standard `article` margins for such a table, but that's just a guess)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% \usepackage{showframe}
\newcolumntype{L}{p{.5\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.1667\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{.1667\textwidth}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|R|R|R|}\hline
Report Tecnico                             & \multicolumn{3}{X|}{Data: XX/YY/ZZ}                                                                                          \\
                                           & \multicolumn{3}{X|}{Nome File : xxxx.yyy}                                                                                    \\\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|X|}{Titolo: }                                                                                                                                            \\
\multicolumn{4}{|X|}{".................."}                                                                                                                                \\\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Progetto o ordine di riferimento:}                                                                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{4}{|X|}{ }                                                                                                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{4}{|X|}{"......................"}                                                                                                                            \\
\multicolumn{4}{|X|}{REF. {\#}data}                                                                                                                                       \\\hline
Autore: AAA BBBB                           & \multicolumn{3}{X|}{}                                                                                                        \\[-7pt]
                                           & \multicolumn{3}{X|}{Descrizione Revisioni}                                                                                   \\[-7pt]
Approvato da: CCC DDDD                     & \multicolumn{3}{X|}{}                                                                                                        \\\hline
\multirow{2}{.35\textwidth}{Destinatari:}  & \multicolumn{3}{p{.57\textwidth}|}{0\qquad Primo rilascio Rev 0 \qquad data}                                                 \\
                                           & \multicolumn{3}{X|}{}                                                                                                        \\
                                           & \multicolumn{3}{p{.57\textwidth}|}{Pagine revisionate}                                                                       \\\cline{2-4}
                                           & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{Paragrafo}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{Revisione} & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{Data} \\[-10pt]
                                           & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{}                                           & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{}     \\\cline{2-4}
                                           &  content will go here content will go here content will go here & content will go here           & content will go here      \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The most fragile part of the table is the `multirow` cell. As a general rule, you need to increase the first argument by one for each `\newline` that you'll use in the code. Test it a bit and you'll see what I mean.

I tried to format the code in a readable way but that was no easy task :) The `showframe` package is there in case you want to test the margins.

Comment: Thanks, this should do the trick. I'll try toying with the widths to see what looks best. Oh, and _ciao_ to you, too.

Comment: Yes, you'll probably need to adjust some of them after the table is filled with content.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach, not based on standard table packages, I tried to play with a combination of `tcolorbox`es and `xcoffin`s. Probably in this case the well-known table approach is simpler, this is just for fun.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
% \usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\NewCoffin{\cL}
\NewCoffin{\cRT}
\NewCoffin{\cRM}
\NewCoffin{\cRB}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newtcolorbox{structure}[1][]{
 enhanced,
 boxrule=0.4pt,
 colback=white,
 colbacktitle=white,
 coltitle=black,
 center title,
 left=.025\textwidth,
 right=.025\textwidth,
 lefttitle=2pt,
 righttitle=2pt,
 arc=0pt,
 outer arc=0pt,
 nobeforeafter,
 before=,
 after=\vspace*{-1pt},
 #1
}

\newcommand{\topbox}[2]{
 \begin{structure}[valign=center,center upper,height=.075\textheight,width=.45\textwidth]
  \textbf{Report tecnico}
 \end{structure}%
 \begin{structure}[valign=center,center upper,height=.075\textheight,width=.55\textwidth]
  \textbf{Data:} #1

  \medskip
  \textbf{Nome file:} #2
 \end{structure}%
}
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{
 \begin{structure}[height=.1\textheight]
  \textbf{Titolo:} #1
 \end{structure}
}
\newcommand{\project}[2]{
 \begin{structure}[height=.15\textheight]
  \textbf{Progetto o ordine di riferimento:}

  \medskip
  #1

  \vskip3em
  \textbf{REF.} #2
 \end{structure}
}
\newcommand{\middlebox}[3]{
 \begin{structure}[valign=center,width=.45\textwidth,height=.1\textheight]
  \textbf{Autore:} #1

  \bigskip
  \textbf{Approvato da:} #2
 \end{structure}%
 \begin{structure}[valign=center,width=.55\textwidth,height=.1\textheight]
  #3
 \end{structure}%
}
\newcommand{\recipients}[1]{%
 \SetHorizontalCoffin{\cL}{%
  \begin{structure}[width=.45\textwidth,height=.575\textheight]
   \textbf{Destinatari:}

   #1
  \end{structure}%
 }%
}
\newcommand{\release}[1]{
 \SetHorizontalCoffin{\cRT}{%
  \begin{structure}[width=.55\textwidth,height=.15\textheight]
   #1
  \end{structure}%
 }%
}
\newcommand{\revisions}[1]{
 \SetHorizontalCoffin{\cRM}{%
  \begin{structure}[width=.55\textwidth,height=.05\textheight]
   \textbf{Pagine revisionate:} #1
  \end{structure}%
 }%
}
\newcommand{\lowerleftbox}[3]{
 \SetHorizontalCoffin{\cRB}{%
  \begin{structure}[width=.2\textwidth,height=.375\textheight,adjusted title={Paragrafo}]
   #1
  \end{structure}%
  \begin{structure}[width=.2\textwidth,height=.375\textheight,adjusted title={Revisione}]
   #2
  \end{structure}%
  \begin{structure}[width=.15\textwidth,height=.375\textheight,adjusted title={Data}]
   #3
  \end{structure}%
 }%
}
\begin{document}
\topbox %
 {10/10/10}
 {filename}
\mytitle
 {Title}
\project
 {.......}
 {\# data}
\middlebox
 {Author}
 {Reviewer}
 {Descrizione revisioni}
\recipients
 {
 Recipent 1

 Recipient 2
 }
\release
{0\qquad Primo rilascio Rev 0 \qquad data}
\revisions
{100}
\lowerleftbox
{A}
{B}
{C}
\JoinCoffins{\cL}[t,r]{\cRT}[t,l](-.1pt, 0cm)%
\JoinCoffins{\cL}[\cRT-b,r]{\cRM}[t,r](-.1pt, 0cm)%
\JoinCoffins{\cL}[\cRM-b,r]{\cRB}[t,r](-.1pt, 0cm)%
\TypesetCoffin{\cL}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Okular users:** Okular has problems with the rules and hides some of them at some zooming levels.

Comment: This is even better. Only, the three columns on the bottom left are a tad asymmetrical, but i guess some minor tweaking will do it. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I made them asymmetrical on purpose so that "revisione" did not hypenate. the total width is `.55\textwidth`, so if you want to have  equal size columns they should be something like `.183\textwidth` each.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be like this

`\documentclass{book}`

`\usepackage{booktabs}`

`\usepackage{multicol}`

`\usepackage{multirow}`

`\begin{document}`

`\begin{table}[h]`

`\centering`

`\begin{tabular}{|l|llc|}`

`\toprule`

`\multirow{2}{*}{Report Tecnico} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Data: XX/YY/ZZ} \\`

`&\multicolumn{3}{l|} {Nome File : xxxx.yyy} \\`

`\midrule`

`\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{ }\\`

`\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Titolo: }\\`

`\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{ }\\`

`\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{".................."}\\`

`\midrule`

`\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Progetto o ordine di riferimento:}\\`

`\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{ }\\`

`\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{"......................"}\\`

`\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{REF. {\#}data}\\`

`\midrule`

`Autore: AAA BBBB &  \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}\\`

`& \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Descrizione Revisioni}\\`

`Approvato da: CCC DDDD & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}\\`

`\midrule`

`\multirow{2}{*}{Destinatari:} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{0  Primo rilascio Rev 0 data}\\`

`& \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}\\ \cline{2-4}`

`Istituzione & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}\\`

`{Nome} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}\\`

`&  \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Pagine revisonate}\\`

`& \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &\\\cline{2-4}`

`&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Paragrapo}&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Revisions} &Date\\`

`& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &\\\cline{2-4}`

`&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}&\\`

`&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}&\\`

`&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}&\\`

`&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}&\\`

`&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}&\\`

`&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}&\\`

`\midrule`

`\bottomrule`

`\end{tabular}`

`\end{table}`

`\end{document}`

[image: multirowtbl]

Comment: Could you reformat your answer please?